# In memory compression of objects in c#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, compression

So I'm all self taught in c# working on a game mod called BlackBox for stardive1.

It's an xna 3.1 game built as x86. I can't change this without a major overhaul which is a little out of my league.

The game hits out of memory issues late game.

It loads a lot of resources during runtime and stores them in dictionaries.

I was wondering if there would be a relatively easy way to do in memory compression of the dictionary object or values in the dictionary.

When a ship is created it copies the data in the dictionary and creates a new object. I was hoping I could compress the dictionary and decompress the values when needed. The performance hit might be worth the extra memory saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think compression would help. Instead you should make sure that every resource gets loaded only when it is necessary and only once.

For example if you have 3 boxes, and each box uses the same 600 mb texture then it would be 1200 mb less if you load only one instance of the texture object than if you load it three times.

And if you get far enough from an object you should delete that texture and load others whom objects get closer.

Comment: The textures and models are referenced on the ship object library as text. I interned the strings that store this and saved a good chunk of ram but I thought of there was a way to compress the less used data it would help. I can look at some way to load the ships on the fly and use the dictionary as a cache instead of storage.

Comment: The ship dictionary is more or less a Skelton that points to objects in other dictionaries that contain the data. But each ship design can contain hundreds of references and there can be thousands of ship designs.